# Recording PCM audio in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, audio-recording, audioformat

I have encountered a strange behavior in Silverlight application and couldn't be able to resolve it after trying many hours.

- Since I cannot access `AudioFormat`'s internal constructor in my code (even using reflection caused silverlight security policies to raise an exception), How can I change audio format (in my class which is derived from `AudioSink` class. Right now, I override the method in my `MemoryAudioSink` class as follows:

  ```
  protected override void OnFormatChange(AudioFormat audioFormat)
  {
      if (this.audioFormat == null)
      {
          this.audioFormat = audioFormat;
      }
      else
      {
          throw new InvalidOperationException();
      }
  }
  ```

  I cannot create new AudioFormat (no ctor available) and the default AudioFomat has 16000 samples per seconds which has no setter. I'd like to record and save audio, in a Mono (Channels = 1), 8 bit(Bits Per Sample = 8), 8k (Samples Per Second = 8000) format.

Also, I have used Cool Edit to record 8bit 8k audio successfully to make sure my sound card supports it.

So simply put, Can I record audio with my custom AudioFormat or should I record the audio in Silverlight, pass it to my WebApp, and convert it to my custom format using a third party library (which I'm not aware of any)?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you: [Silverlight 4 audio recording and upload to server](http://www.gajotres.com/post/2011/09/06/Silverlight-4-audio-recording-and-upload-to-server-part-1.aspx)
Sry for my stupidity I dont know how to format code, in that link I gave you, look for line AudioFormat desiredAudioFormat = null; go there, you need next foreach