# Converting wav file to wav file (changing format)

Tags: c#, wav, audioformat

Trying to find a workaround for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7175217/337294), I'd like to convert a 16k 8bit mono wav which is written in `byte[]` (which has wav header) to a 8k 8bit mono stream/byte[].

Is there any .Net library with samples available for this kind of conversion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I ended up using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) and with the following snippet, Voila! Everything works like a charm:

```
WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat(8000, 8 , 1);
WaveStream stream =new WaveFileReader("c:\\test.wav");
WaveFormatConversionStream str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, stream);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("c:\\converted.wav", str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alvas seems to support conversion as well as the usual features:

http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx